# Python setting dynamic value to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following sample dict format which i need to build where `number, description` will populate dynamically.

```
{
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {},
    "body": {
      "message": {
        "messageId": 22,
        "messageVersion": 3
      },
      "number": 1112223333,
      "description": "Test Message"
    }
}
```

There is one file which contains `number, description` e.g.
data.dat which contains following

```
1, mydecription1  
2 , mydecription2
so on...
```

Is there anyway to achieve this  where i am replacing the `number, description` after reading the file..

Comment: You can read the file and split each line with `,`.

Comment: Is every other value in the dictionary static? If so, make your "template" dictionary, and then when reading your files, do whatever processing you need to do and update a **deepcopy** of your template dictionary and populate with `{**template_copy, "number": num, "description": desc}`.

Comment: @BoseongChoi its DAT file which contain the number and description in each line

Comment: By the way, @blorgon, that's a shallow copy not a deep copy.

Comment: @blorgon thanks for reply, can u pls share some example,  I am newbie in python.

Comment: @BoseongChoi I updated to unpack a `template_copy`, which I implicitly explain should be a deepcopy.

Comment: @blorgon Oh I get it. I misunderstood the sentence.

Comment: @user1591156 Start from `with open('/your/file/path') as f: print([line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()])
`! You can do it by yourself.

Comment: @user1591156 are you asking how to read your data from a file, or how to put your data into a dictionary?

Comment: @blorgon, i can read the file but how to put data in dictionary

Comment: @user1591156 see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're *not* asking us how to read your data file, and have already figured that out. I'm also assuming a lot about your workflow here. Do you need all of these dictionaries at once, or one at a time? It's not clear from your post so this is *a* possible approach:

```py
from copy import deepcopy  # std lib, no need to install anything


template = {"method": "POST",
            "headers": {},
            "body": {"message": {"messageId": 22, "messageVersion": 3}}}


# Read in all your num, desc pairs
data = []
with open("my_file.DAT", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # get number and description
        data.append(dict(number=num, description=desc))


for data_dict in data:
    template_copy = deepcopy(template)
    template_copy["body"].update(data_dict)
    # do something with your now-complete dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you'll read the file. Will you use something like this?

```
import pandas
df =  pandas.read_csv("path_to_file")
```

Then with that you could iterrows like so:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
     your_dict["number"] = row["number"]
     your_dict["description" = row["description"]
```

But guess we need more info about your constraints.

Comment: Why import Pandas, a very heavy dependency, just to read a CSV? Python has a built-in CSV reader...